# What is causing VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST when calling vkQueueSubmit?

Tags: c++, vulkan, voxel

I'm working on a voxel engine in C++ using Vulkan. Most of the boilerplate code is heavily based on [vulkan-tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/). I have a drawFrame function that looks like this...

```
void drawFrame(float dt) {
    vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);

    uint32_t imageIndex;
    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

    updateUniformBuffer(imageIndex, dt);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
        return;
    } else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }

    // Check if a previous frame is using this image (i.e.there is its fence to wait on)
    if (imagesInFlight[imageIndex] != VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &imagesInFlight[imageIndex], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
    }
    // Mark the image as now being in use by this frame
    imagesInFlight[imageIndex] = inFlightFences[currentFrame];

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame] };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[imageIndex];

    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame] };
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    vkResetFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame]);

    result = vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame]);
    if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
    }

    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo{};
    presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
    presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { swapChain };
    presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;
    presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;
    presentInfo.pResults = nullptr; // Optional

    result = vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || framebufferResized) {
        framebufferResized = false;
        recreateSwapChain();
    } else if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
    }

    // Increment the frame. By using the modulo(%) operator, we ensure that the frame index loops around after every MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT enqueued frames.
    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % config->maxFramesInFlight;
}
```

I'm passing in vertices like this...

```
void createVertexAndIndexBuffer() {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            for (size_t z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
                // for each block in the world vector
                auto blockId = world.getBlock(x, y, z);
                if (blockId == BlockId::Air) {
                    continue;
                }
                Vec3 blockPosition = { x, y, z };

                // get its data
                auto verts = blockdb.blockDataFor(blockId).getVertices();
                auto inds = blockdb.blockDataFor(blockId).getIndices();

                // account for the block position and store the new verts for later
                for (int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++) {
                    Vertex v(verts[i]);
                    v.pos += blockPosition;
                    vertices.push_back(v);
                }

                // store the indices for later accounting for the offset into the verts vector
                for (int i = 0; i < inds.size(); i++) {
                    int ind(inds[i] + vertices.size());
                    indices.push_back(ind);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // time to start creating the actual buffer 
    VkDeviceSize vertexBufferSize = sizeof(vertices[0]) * vertices.size();

    VkBuffer vertexStagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory vertexStagingBufferMemory;
    
    createBuffer(vertexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, vertexStagingBuffer, vertexStagingBufferMemory);

    void* vertexData;
    vkMapMemory(device, vertexStagingBufferMemory, 0, vertexBufferSize, 0, &vertexData);
    memcpy(vertexData, vertices.data(), (size_t)vertexBufferSize); 
    vkUnmapMemory(device, vertexStagingBufferMemory);

    createBuffer(vertexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, vertexBuffer, vertexBufferMemory);

    // use copyBuffer() to move the vertex data to the device local buffer
    copyBuffer(vertexStagingBuffer, vertexBuffer, vertexBufferSize);

    // After copying the data from the staging buffer to the device buffer, we should clean up the staging buffer since it is no longer needed.
    vkDestroyBuffer(device, vertexStagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, vertexStagingBufferMemory, nullptr);


    // and do the same for the index buffer
    VkDeviceSize indexBufferSize = sizeof(indices[0]) * indices.size();

    VkBuffer indexStagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory indexStagingBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(indexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, indexStagingBuffer, indexStagingBufferMemory);

    void* indexData;
    vkMapMemory(device, indexStagingBufferMemory, 0, indexBufferSize, 0, &indexData);
    memcpy(indexData, indices.data(), (size_t)indexBufferSize);
    vkUnmapMemory(device, indexStagingBufferMemory);

    createBuffer(indexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_INDEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, indexBuffer, indexBufferMemory);

    copyBuffer(indexStagingBuffer, indexBuffer, indexBufferSize);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, indexStagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, indexStagingBufferMemory, nullptr);
}
```

Everything works fine like that but I need be able to render by chunk instead of by block in order to implement chunk geometry optimizations. This is my chunk.h and chunk.cpp...

```
#pragma once
#include "Layer.h"

class Chunk {
public:
    Chunk() = default;
    Chunk(World* _world, Vec2XZ pos);
    ~Chunk() {}

    BlockId getBlock(int x, int y, int z);
    bool setBlock(BlockId id, int x, int y, int z);
    bool isBlockOutOfBounds(int x, int y, int z);
    void generateVerticesAndIndices();
    void load();

    std::array<Layer, CHUNK_HEIGHT> layers;
    const Vec2XZ position;
    const World* world;
    bool isLoaded = false;
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<uint32_t> indices;
private:
};
```

```
#pragma once
#include "Chunk.h"

Chunk::Chunk(World* _world, Vec2XZ pos) :
    position(pos),
    world(_world) {
}

BlockId Chunk::getBlock(int x, int y, int z) {
    if (isBlockOutOfBounds(x, y, z)) {
        return BlockId::Air;
    }

    return layers[y].getBlock(x, z);
}

bool Chunk::setBlock(BlockId id, int x, int y, int z) {
    if (!isBlockOutOfBounds(x, y, z)) {
        if (layers[y].setBlock(id, x, z)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool Chunk::isBlockOutOfBounds(int x, int y, int z) {
    if (x >= CHUNK_WIDTH)
        return true;
    if (z >= CHUNK_WIDTH)
        return true;

    if (x < 0)
        return true;
    if (y < 0)
        return true;
    if (z < 0)
        return true;

    if (y >= CHUNK_HEIGHT) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void Chunk::generateVerticesAndIndices() {
    vertices.clear();
    indices.clear();
    for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_WIDTH; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_WIDTH; z++) {
                // for each block in this chunk
                auto blockId = getBlock(x, y, z);

                if (blockId == BlockId::Air) {
                    continue; // dont render air
                }
                
                // infer the block position using its coordinates
                Vec3 blockPosition = { x, y, z };

                // get its data
                auto verts = world->blockdb->blockDataFor(blockId).getVertices();
                auto inds = world->blockdb->blockDataFor(blockId).getIndices();

                // account for the block position and store the new verts
                for (int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++) {
                    Vertex v(verts[i]);
                    v.pos += blockPosition;
                    vertices.push_back(v);
                }

                // store the indices for later accounting for the offset into the verts vector
                for (int i = 0; i < inds.size(); i++) {
                    int ind(inds[i] + vertices.size());
                    indices.push_back(ind);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Chunk::load() {
    if (isLoaded) {
        return;
    }

    // todo: actual terrain generation
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_WIDTH; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_WIDTH; z++) {
                setBlock(BlockId::Grass, x, y, z);
            }
        }
    }

    isLoaded = true;
}
```

So I've basically migrated the top part of createVertexAndIndexBuffer() over to the chunk class. Then within createVertexAndIndexBuffer(), I iterate through the chunks around the player within render distance like this...

```
 void createVertexAndIndexBuffer() {
    // set bounds of how far out to render based on what chunk the player is in
    Vec2XZ playerChunkCoords = { floor(player.position.x) / CHUNK_WIDTH, floor(player.position.z) / CHUNK_WIDTH };

    Vec2XZ lowChunkXZ = { playerChunkCoords.x - renderDistance, playerChunkCoords.z - renderDistance };
    Vec2XZ highChunkXZ = { playerChunkCoords.x + renderDistance, playerChunkCoords.z + renderDistance };

    // for each chunk around the player within render distance
    for (int x = lowChunkXZ.x; x < highChunkXZ.x; x++) {
        for (int z = lowChunkXZ.z; z < highChunkXZ.z; z++) {
            // get the chunk
            Chunk* chunk = &world.getChunk(x, z);

            // load it if it isnt already
            if (!chunk->isLoaded) {
                chunk->load();
            }

            // generate its geometry if it doesnt already exist
            if (chunk->vertices.size() == 0 || chunk->indices.size() == 0) {
                chunk->generateVerticesAndIndices();
            }

            auto verts = chunk->vertices;
            auto inds = chunk->indices;

            // account for the chunk position and store the new verts for later
            for (int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++) {
                Vertex v(verts[i]);
                v.pos.x += x * CHUNK_WIDTH;
                v.pos.z += z * CHUNK_WIDTH;
                vertices.push_back(v);
            }

            // store the indices for later accounting for the offset into the verts vector
            for (int i = 0; i < inds.size(); i++) {
                int ind(inds[i] + vertices.size());
                indices.push_back(ind);
            }
        }
    }

    // time to start creating the actual buffer 
    VkDeviceSize vertexBufferSize = sizeof(vertices[0]) * vertices.size();

    VkBuffer vertexStagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory vertexStagingBufferMemory;
    
    createBuffer(vertexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, vertexStagingBuffer, vertexStagingBufferMemory);

    void* vertexData;
    vkMapMemory(device, vertexStagingBufferMemory, 0, vertexBufferSize, 0, &vertexData);
    memcpy(vertexData, vertices.data(), (size_t)vertexBufferSize); 
    vkUnmapMemory(device, vertexStagingBufferMemory);

    createBuffer(vertexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, vertexBuffer, vertexBufferMemory);

    // use copyBuffer() to move the vertex data to the device local buffer
    copyBuffer(vertexStagingBuffer, vertexBuffer, vertexBufferSize);

    // After copying the data from the staging buffer to the device buffer, we should clean up the staging buffer since it is no longer needed.
    vkDestroyBuffer(device, vertexStagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, vertexStagingBufferMemory, nullptr);


    // and do the same for the index buffer
    VkDeviceSize indexBufferSize = sizeof(indices[0]) * indices.size();

    VkBuffer indexStagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory indexStagingBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(indexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, indexStagingBuffer, indexStagingBufferMemory);

    void* indexData;
    vkMapMemory(device, indexStagingBufferMemory, 0, indexBufferSize, 0, &indexData);
    memcpy(indexData, indices.data(), (size_t)indexBufferSize);
    vkUnmapMemory(device, indexStagingBufferMemory);

    createBuffer(indexBufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_INDEX_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, indexBuffer, indexBufferMemory);

    copyBuffer(indexStagingBuffer, indexBuffer, indexBufferSize);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, indexStagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, indexStagingBufferMemory, nullptr);
}
```

With this code, the engine starts up fine but the screen stays white and then after a few calls to vkQueueSubmit() within drawFrame(), vkQueueSubmit() returns VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST instead of VK_SUCCESS and then the app throws the corresponding runtime error, prints out the corresponding debug information "failed to submit draw command buffer!", waits for me to press a key, and then finally terminates with EXIT_FAILURE.

Why does pushing vertices from blocks directly work fine, but pushing them from chunks does not? I have checked the Vulkan specification and did a lot of googling but I just couldn't find much on what causes this error to be thrown. I want to know how to fix it and in turn, fix my engine.

Comment: IDK how you expect help to do debugging for you. Reduce the problem down.

Comment: Reduce the problem down to what? I know the vertices are loading correctly because I've looked through the vector after the function call. Same with the indices. It's the same vertex data, just being put into the pipeline from a different source and now suddenly it doesn't work. There is no output from the validation layers indicating what the problem might be. The call to vkQueueSubmit works for about half a second and the program loops a few times and then out of nowhere, it throws VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST. Its like the gpu is hanging or something but the cpu isnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was assigning indices incorrectly and it was being caught by the graphics driver. There were indices that were larger than the vertex vector.